# Searching a specific string on a file.txt python3

Tags: python, python-3.x

How do I search for a specific string on file like for example string 'A' then will print all lines that contains the string 'S'

```
def reader():
    path = 'path'
    file = open(path,'r')
    txtfile = file.read()
```

My string:

Sample
Not 
Working
Example

Output should be like:

Sample only because it contains 'S'

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow ! Please, after doing the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), be sure to have a look at [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Then, edit the question adding a sample of your data and the expected output.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, that you need to search a word in a line and, if it matches then print the line.

f=open(filename,'r')
data=f.readlines()
for line in data:
    if "your_search_string" in line:
        print(line)